# How to bridge my gateway device to Homekit?

Tags: ios, iphone, gateway, homekit

I want to develop a gateway device that it can be communicate with Homekit. 
I have some question:
1. How to make APP search the device?
2. How the device send data to Homekit?

Comment: Your question is too broad, but Apple has now provided a non-commercial access to the [HomeKit specification](https://developer.apple.com/homekit/specification/) although the license would seem to prohibit creating open-source implementations so I haven't agreed to it and I can't tell you whats in it.  You could also check out [Homebridge](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge) - I found it pretty easy to set up and I have created a couple of plugins to talk to hardware I already had.  If you want to create a product for sale then you need to go through MFi

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you . I have been reading the  [HomeKit Accessory Protocol Specification](https://developer.apple.com//homekit/specification/) for a few days, it seems too broad, and I don't know how to do according to it. And, the [Homebridge](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge), can all of the gateway device bridge to Homekit? I saw someone using it bridge [Xiaomi's](https://list.mi.com/130) equipment to Homekit.

Comment: Homebridge is a bridge.  It can expose 100 accessories to HomeKit.  Is the gateway device just for your own use or is it for a commercial product?

Comment: Gateway device is a product of my company, it will be commercial product. And I don't want to pass MFi certification now.

Comment: Then you can get started with the open documentation and move to MFi certification when you are ready to sell it.  HomeKit won't work for you in this case as you need to run the code inside your gateway.  Writing a HomeKit plugin may help you understand accessories, services and characteristics however

Comment: OK, I'll try to do it. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is a complex system.  Unfortunately there are no shortcuts